# How can I select with column of lists

Tags: kdb

Say I have a table with a column of lists

```
q)t:([]x:10?1.;y:10?`a`b`c;z:10#enlist`a`b)
q)t
x          y z  
----------------
0.1627662  b a b
0.6884756  b a b
0.8177547  a a b
0.7520102  b a b
0.1086824  c a b
0.9598964  c a b
0.03668341 a a b
0.6430982  a a b
0.6708738  b a b
0.6789082  a a b
```

How can I select for rows `where y in z` ?

Comment: Why the F*** do I get -1 and a close vote ? This is perfectly legit question ! Usual select from t where y in z do not work as z is a list of list...

Comment: Be careful with 'in' as it is rank sensitive. If your 'z' col has nested lists then  you might not get the desired results. check: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/personal-kdbplus/behaviour%7Csort:relevance/personal-kdbplus/2L5tMOVKung/-OtW_wlpPFAJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select from t where y in'z

As z is a list of lists, you require an each. The ' acts as each-both.
http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#672-each-both
for more detail. Beware whitespace.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/personal-kdbplus for more knowledgable advice.